# How to stop the function when single shot, but enable while spray/auto shooting

Tags: lua, logitech

I made a small anti-recoil script for LUA logitech gaming mouse and it seems that it does the function but when I single shot it does the whole thing and doesn't stop when mousebutton is not pressed:

```
    function OnEvent(event, arg)
    OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %d\n", event, arg)
    if (event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED") then
        EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
    elseif event == "PROFILE_DEACTIVATED" then
        ReleaseMouseButton(2)
    end
    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5) then
        kaki = not kaki
        kus = not kus
    end
   if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and kaki) then
        if kaki then
            repeat
                Sleep(50)
                MoveMouseRelative(0, 1)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(0, 16)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(0, 26)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(-2, 25)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(10, 28)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(8, 25)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(10, 15)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(-14, 15)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(-34, -1)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(-18, 0)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(10, 10)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(-13, 5)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(-20, -5)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(-5, 0)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(33, 3)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(15, 6)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(15, 5)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(20, 0)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(28, -10)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(-15, 4)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(5, 0)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(-8, 8)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(-6, 4)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(3, -2)
                MoveMouseRelative(13, 0)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(5, 0)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(-15, 0)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(-30, 0)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(-35, -13)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(-13, -4)
                Sleep(100)
            until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
        end
    end
end
```

Any suggestions on how to cancel the function mid-way or when mouse button is not pressed and the loop will not complete and end where the last shot was fired.

(In the game when I shoot single shot - the mouse move the whole recoil procedure)

Answer (score 0):

Try using coroutine.

```
if kaki then
     local cor = coroutine.create(function()
     MoveMouseRelative(0, 1)
     coroutine.yield()
     MoveMouseRelative(0, 16)
     coroutine.yield()
     MoveMouseRelative(0, 26)
     coroutine.yield()
     MoveMouseRelative(-2, 25)
     coroutine.yield()
     MoveMouseRelative(10, 28)
     coroutine.yield()
     MoveMouseRelative(8, 25)
     coroutine.yield()
     MoveMouseRelative(10, 15)
     coroutine.yield()
     MoveMouseRelative(-14, 15)
     coroutine.yield()
     MoveMouseRelative(-34, -1)
     coroutine.yield()
     MoveMouseRelative(-18, 0)
     coroutine.yield()
     MoveMouseRelative(10, 10)
     coroutine.yield()
     MoveMouseRelative(-13, 5)
     coroutine.yield()
     MoveMouseRelative(-20, -5)
     coroutine.yield()
     MoveMouseRelative(-5, 0)
     coroutine.yield()
     MoveMouseRelative(33, 3)
     coroutine.yield()
     MoveMouseRelative(15, 6)
     coroutine.yield()
     MoveMouseRelative(15, 5)
     coroutine.yield()
     MoveMouseRelative(20, 0)
     coroutine.yield()
     MoveMouseRelative(28, -10)
     coroutine.yield()
     MoveMouseRelative(-15, 4)
     coroutine.yield()
     MoveMouseRelative(5, 0)
     coroutine.yield()
     MoveMouseRelative(-8, 8)
     coroutine.yield()
     MoveMouseRelative(-6, 4)
     coroutine.yield()
     MoveMouseRelative(3, -2)
     MoveMouseRelative(13, 0)
     coroutine.yield()
     MoveMouseRelative(5, 0)
     coroutine.yield()
     MoveMouseRelative(-15, 0)
     coroutine.yield()
     MoveMouseRelative(-30, 0)
     coroutine.yield()
     MoveMouseRelative(-35, -13)
     coroutine.yield()
     MoveMouseRelative(-13, -4)
  end)
  coroutine.resume(cor)
  repeat
     Sleep(100)
     coroutine.resume(cor)
  until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
end
```